Conorm and the boundary of the linear transformation of unit ball
This is a question from the chapter 5 of Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis book:

The conorm of a linear transformation
$T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is
$$m(T) = \inf \left\{ \frac{|Tv|}{|v|}: v \neq 0  \right\}.$$ It
is the minimum stretch that $T$ imparts to vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n.$
Let $U$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Show that the conorm of
$T$ is the radius of the largest ball contained in $TU.$

I guess the conorm of $T$ is the radius of the largest ball contained in $TU$ iff the boundary of $TU$ is $TS^{n-1}$, where $S^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But how can I show that the boundary of $TU$ is $TS^{n-1}$? Do I need to assume that the norm on both $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ is the Euclidean norm, or I can proceed with a general norm?

This forum is not for hep with textbook exercises.
